# WPF Setter not working on some controls

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I am trying to use a setter in my application to change to font size of all Controls. My Style is looking like this:

```
<Style x:Key="baseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Width, ConverterParameter=1000, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToBoolConverter}, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

All of my substyles are looking like this

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    ...
</Style>
```

My problem is that my styles isnot applied to all controls. Labels for example seam to ignore my FontSize Setter

Default Style:
[image: Default Style]

Triggered Style:
[image: Triggered Style]

Comment: Y u make sub styles remove substyles make styles for the controller

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually refer to `Label` elements or `TextBlock` elements? Because the latter type is not a `Control` and won't be affected by your `Style`. This should work though:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" />
```

Comment: my baseStyles target is x:Type Control isn't this supposed to set all controls including labels?

Comment: All *Controls* but a TextBlock is not a Control.

Comment: I am using labels and labels are controls.

Comment: Then it should work as I mentioned in my answer. Please provde your point if it doesn't: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve